# Accept drag & drop of image from another browser window

Tags: javascript, html

In Javascript, I know how to set up a drag & drop target that accepts file uploads from the user's computer. How can I set up a drop target that accepts images that are dragged from another website? All I need to know is the URL of the image that they've dragged.

I know this is possible, since Google Docs accepts image drops from other websites. Any idea how they're doing it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

UPDATE:

It looks like there are differences between Chrome on Windows and MacOS. On Windows `dataTransfer.getData('Text');` works but not on MacOS. `dataTransfer.getData('URL');` should work on both.

---

OLD answer:

You could define a drop zone:

```
<div id="dropbox">DropZone => you could drop any image from any page here</div>
```

and then handle the `dragenter`, `dragexit`, `dragover` and `drop` events:

```
var dropbox = document.getElementById('dropbox');

dropbox.addEventListener('dragenter', noopHandler, false);
dropbox.addEventListener('dragexit', noopHandler, false);
dropbox.addEventListener('dragover', noopHandler, false);
dropbox.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);

function noopHandler(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
}
function drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault(); 
    var imageUrl = evt.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    alert(imageUrl);
}
```

​
It is inside the `drop` event handler that we are reading the image data from the `dataTransfer` object as Text. If we dropped an image from some other webpage this text will represent the url of the image.

And here's a [`live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/kkcMH/7/).

Comment: This is alerting a blank string in Chrome

Comment: @Duopixel, that's very weird. It works for me: Chrome 21.0, Windows 7 64 bit. What OS are you using? Does it work with FF?

Comment: Chrome 21 MacOS 10.7.4. Perhaps other MacOS user can confirm, anyone? It does work in Firefox.

Comment: I can confirm that it does not work in Chrome 21.0.1180.79 Mac OS X 10.8, but does work in Firefox 14.0.1.

Comment: Looks like Chrome on MacOS uses `dataTransfer.getData('url');`.

Comment: getData('Text') doesn't work in chromium 22.0.1221.0 on a mac, but does in Firefox 14.0.1 on the same mac. Whereas getData('URL') works in both.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I read your comment before you edited it ;) I'll boot up my VM and see if it's the same here. In the meantime, you could just check the value of one of them, and if it's null just use the other value, right?

Comment: @SimonM, actually `getData('URL')` seems to work everywhere and is the correct method to use.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It makes more sense, why would you get an image URL by requesting Text? Anyway, in windows both Text and URL seem to work, in chrome and firefox. Weird...

Comment: `getData('URL')` doesn't work when the dragged image is a link, but I can't find another way to get the information about dragged object... it seems that instead of image the object is the link that contains that image

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Darin `getData('URL')` seems to be the right solution here.

Comment: It has an issue with local files, undoubtedly for security reasons. The file has to be remote for this to work.

Comment: Checked recently and this answer is working on Firefox 46.0.1, Chrome 50.0.2661, Edge 25.10586, and Internet Explorer 11.306.

Comment: It was a useful explanation

Answer (score 4):

```
function drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var imageUrl = evt.dataTransfer.getData('URL');  // instead of 'Text'
    alert(imageUrl);
}
```

Seems to work in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome on Mac. Also works in Firefox, IE, and Chrome in Windows.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zever/EcxSm/)

Comment: What version? It's working here on Windows 7, Chrome 21.0.1180.79

Comment: this doesn't work when the dragged image is a link, it alerts the link url (on Chrome/Mac) or blank string (on Safari/Mac) instead of image url

Answer (score 4):

Although you are able to accept the drag and drop of an image from another website, you are unable to do any processing of it (e.g. converting it to a base64 string using the canvas) (as of 21st August 2014) because of various cross-origin policy issues.

```
var dt = event.dataTransfer;
var url = dt.getData('url');
if (!url) {
    url = dt.getData('text/plain');
    if (!url) {
        url = dt.getData('text/uri-list');
            if (!url) {
                // We have tried all that we can to get this url but we can't. Abort mission
                 return;
             }
         }
     }
```

Even Google can't get around this - If you use gmail, you can drag and drop an image from another location in to the email body, but all this does is create an `<img/>` element with its `src` set to `url` (from the code above).

However, I've created a plugin that allows you to fake it cross-origin drag and drop. It requires a PHP backend.

Read the article I wrote on it here https://coderwall.com/p/doco6w/html5-cross-origin-drag-and-drop

Comment: It would seem that not only cross-platform issues can prevent you from retrieving the URL, but also mixed content.

Comment: That nested conditional looks like something `reduce` would do well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution to the problem: [Dropzone js - Drag n Drop file from same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816375/dropzone-js-drag-n-drop-file-from-same-page/43041683#43041683)

Please do keep in mind that ability to drag an image from *another* domain depends on their CORS setup.

Comment: The fact that this feature is depending on the CORS-Setup from the other domain was the most important info here!

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers use text/plain some use text/html as well

This code should pull any text or image source url on the latest Chrome, FF on Mac and PC.

Safari doesn't seem to give the URL so if someone knows how to get it let me know.

I'm still working on IE.

```
function getAnyText(theevent) {
//see if we have anything in the text or img src tag
    var insert_text;
    var location = theevent.target;
    var etext;
    var ehtml;
    try {
            etext = theevent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    } catch (_error) {}
    try {
            ehtml = theevent.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    } catch (_error) {}
    if (etext) {
            insert_text = etext;
    } else if (ehtml) {
            object = $('<div/>').html(ehtml).contents();
            if (object) {
                    insert_text =  object.closest('img').prop('src');
            }
    }
    if (insert_text) {
            insertText(insert_text,location);
    }
}
```

Comment: `theevent.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");` is very useful. Than you very much...

Comment: I found that I had to try closest('img') and children('img') on Firefox in the event that the image being dragged was contained in an <a> element.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers correctly state: It normally depends on the CORS-Settings of the server if drag & drop from another browser window is possible ([`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) has to be set).

However I've just found out by chance that it's possible to drap & drop any images from a Firefox (current version 68.0.1) to a Chrome window (current version 76.0.3809) and process it in Javascript, regardless if CORS headers are set or not.

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/y1qert8L/) (based on jsfiddle of Darin Dimitrov) which accepts and directly shows images from:

1. drag and drop from local computer (e.g. from file explorer)
2. drag and drop from other website, if CORS headers are set, e.g. an image from https://imgur.com/
3. drag and drop any images from Firefox window to Chrome window:

   - open jsfiddle demo in Chrome
   - open e.g. google image search in Firefox and search for any image
   - click on the image for bigger preview
   - drag & drop the preview image to the jsfiddle demo in Chrome

However this seems to be kind of a bug of Firefox and therefore I would not rely on this behaviour in an productive application.