# how to upload image file from url using FileReader API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

In html form, we have a image field, to upload a file. I followed tutorial from http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api and it works fine when uploading a image file from local disk.

But suppose i have a image url say http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png and want to upload this image from remote url instead of uploading from local disk.

`FileReader` API works well when trying upload image from local disk but how can we use it to load images by urls?

Its easy to create a `base64` of image and use it for preview by setting in image field as `<img src='data:image/png;base64,iAks4ds__base64__string' id='user_img'>` but what workflow should one adopt to upload images from remote url using jQuery or JavaScript?

How can i? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just get it on the server with curl or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript

Comment: I agree about using curl.  My approach is to use a drag and drop (like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11973398/1798697), retrieve the URL and submit the URL to the server (instead of the actual file data).  When the server gets a URL, it uses curl (or w/e x-server thing) to get its own copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileReader` API is dedicated to **local files** (cf http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

If you want to download an image from a remote URL and extract its data in javascript you can use `Image` and `Canvas` elements, as explained in the following question: [Convert an image into binary data in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript)

Comment: That not going to work any more. `SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Comment: I wans't aware of this security limitation. Thx for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

as [@fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569558/fiddler) answer says, fileReader is for local files only, 
if you need to get things like images from remote urls, then you may follow another approach
1) [using Http Get request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11901662/6885735)
2) [using Canvas features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5420409/6885735)

but due to security threat, browsers not allow scripts to do cross origin requests, only DOM itself can do that. that can be solve by
1) Cors  (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) [?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
2) Jsonp [?](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/using-jsonp-for-cross-domain-requests/)

now you curious so [cors or jsonp](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/cors-and-jsonp.html)

if you have access to server where your remote things exist you can do server side cors [?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control), which is recommended by most.

but as question looking for a solution which can handle any remote resources, cors proxy [?](https://walac.github.io/cors-proxy/) help you

[free cors proxies](https://siderite.blogspot.com/2017/03/free-cors-proxies.html)