# Send default image with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi guys how can i convert a image to object in this code for example:

```
var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); 
img.attr('src', 'http://macreationdentreprise.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ouvrir-un-restaurant.jpeg');
var obj=img.ConvertToObject();
// so i can now use obj.filename; and obj.data;
```

The reason to do that is if i wan't to upload this image automatically if the input file isn't set:

```
<input id="picture_zone_upload_input_ID" type="file" name="picture_zone_upload_input" class="picture_zone_upload_input" multiple title="Choose a file to upload"/>
```

**EDIT**

```
function configure_zone_upload() {
    $("#picture_zone_upload_input_ID").change(function (event) {
        $.each(event.target.files, function (index, file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (event) {
                object = {};
                object.filename = file.name;
                object.data = event.target.result;
                //alert("index: " + index);
                upload_img_count++;
                configure_upload_img(object.data, upload_img_count);

                files.push(object);

            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

        var files = event.target.files;
        for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
            data.append(x, files[x]);
        }
        //alert(files.length);
         AJAX_upload_Profile(data, upload_img_count);

    });
}
```

If there isn't a input file how can i set the my default image to send it with ajax ??

**EDIT2**

If `event.target.files;` is null how can i set file from new image:

```
var files = event.target.files;
            for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                data.append(x, files[x]);
            }
            //alert(files.length);
             AJAX_upload_Profile(data, upload_img_count);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a DOM Element from a JQuery Selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677880/how-to-get-a-dom-element-from-a-jquery-selector)

Comment: What do you mean by converting to object? Are you trying to get binary data of the image?

Comment: @MotiAzu If the input file is chosen i send data to controller by ajax in form of object so if i can convert this img to object i cant send it woth ajax

Comment: @MotiAzu Check the edit

Comment: This should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903812/how-to-upload-image-file-from-url-using-filereader-api

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this:

```
object.filename = file.name || defaultImg;
```

where `defaultImg` is a variable which contains a default img with src.

---

somthing like:

```
reader.onload = function (event) {
    object = {};
    object.defaultImg = $('<img>',{"src" : "defaultImg/path/img.jpeg"}); // <--declare here
    object.filename = file.name 
    object.data = event.target.result || object.defaultImg; //<---use it here;
    //alert("index: " + index);
    upload_img_count++;
    configure_upload_img(object.data, upload_img_count);

    files.push(object);
};
```

Comment: howa can i convert `var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); ` to file ?

Comment: @Omar check the second one.

Comment: in `object.filename` or `.data` ?

Comment: The Problem is when is not changed this block isn't executed so i post null with Ajax

Comment: may be you want to take a look at `document.createElement()` method.